# I am not getting expected output of for while and while loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
import sys

target_int = input("How many integers?")
try:
target_int = int(target_int)

except ValueError:
sys.exit("You must input an integer")
ints = list()
count = 0

while count < target_int:

new_int = input("Please enter {0}:".format(count+1))
isint = False

try:
    new_int = int(new_int)
except:
    print("You must enter an integer")
    if isint == True:
        ints.append(new_int)
        count += 1

print("Using a for loop")
for value in ints:
    print(str(value))

print("Using a while loop")
total = len(ints)
count = 0

while count < total:
    print(str(ints[count]))
    count += 1
```

**OUTPUT is:**

```
How many integers?4
Please enter 1:12
Please enter 1:2 
Please enter 1:21
Please enter 1:34
Please enter 1:23
Please enter 1:23
```

**Expected OUTPUT should be**

```
How many integers? 4
Please enter integer 1: t
You must enter an integer
Please enter integer 1: 5
Please enter integer 2: 2
Please enter integer 3: 6
Please enter integer 3: 6
```

**Using a for loop**

```
5
2
6
9
```

**Using a while loop**

```
5
2
6
9
```

Comment: Please paste the code with the correct indentation so other people can run it without having to fix it manually.

Comment: Your `count` didn't change when your input correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't increment `count` when you're building `ints`, and you've written the loop such that it won't finish until `count` reaches the target.  You don't really need the loop to be written that way in the first place, though; just check `len(ints)` to see how many ints have been entered instead of keeping your own counter that mirrors the length.

```
try:
    num_ints = int(input("How many integers? "))
except ValueError:
    exit("You must input an integer.")

ints = []
while len(ints) < num_ints:
    try:
        ints.append(int(input(f"Please enter {len(ints)+1}: ")))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter an integer")

print("Using a for loop")
for v in ints:
    print(v)

print("Using a while loop")
while ints:
    print(ints.pop(0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked now, it's better and more simplified than my version.